# What Python tools can I use to interface with a website's API?

Tags: python, web-services, twitter

Let's say I wanted to make a python script interface with a site like Twitter.

What would I use to do that? I'm used to using curl/wget from bash, but Python seems to be much nicer to use. What's the equivalent?

(This isn't Python run from a webserver, but run locally via the command line)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

For something like Twitter, you'll save yourself a ton of time by not reinventing the wheel. Try a library like [python-twitter](http://code.google.com/p/python-twitter/). This way, you can write your script, or even a full fledged application, that interfaces with Twitter, and you don't have to care about the implementation details.

If you want to roll your own interface library, you're going to have to get familiar with [urllib](https://docs.python.org/library/urllib.html) and depending on what format they provide results, either [lxml](http://lxml.de/) (or some other xml parser) or [simplejson](http://undefined.org/python/#simplejson).

Comment: urllib, lxml and simplejson sound like the tools I need. Thanks!

Comment: @Rich: if you found this helpful, then you know what you must do... wink wink nudge nudge

Answer (score 5):

Python has urllib2, which is extensible library for opening URLs

Full-featured easy to use library.

https://docs.python.org/library/urllib2.html

Answer (score 4):

I wholeheartedly recommend [mechanize](http://wwwsearch.sourceforge.net/mechanize/) for python. It's exactly a programmable web browser that you can use from python, which handles forms and cookies as well! It makes any kind of site crawling a breeze.

Take a look at the examples on that link to see what it can do.

Comment: Mechanize is ideal for situations where you DON'T have an API, but the OP specifies a site like Twitter, which has an API, so urllib2 is usually the way to go.

Comment: ah, i didn't exactly get what you meant by "has an API" - but you mean it has an extensive way of interfacing with it just through URLs. in that case, yeah, urllib2 should be sufficient.

Comment: “It makes any kind of site crawling a breeze.” — except where the site is setting cookie values via JavaScript, and relying on them, as I’m finding to my chagrin.

Comment: @Paul: ah true.. ive had that problem as well. i have wanted to make a mechanize that can parse and execute javascript as i haven't seen one that does, but no time yet.

Comment: sure. I’m currently attempting to use [Selenium](http://seleniumhq.org/), which is a bit more heavyweight (and actually relies on having an actual browser installed on your system, which is fine locally but more of an issue if you’re trying to run it on a shared hosting server somewhere).

Answer (score 2):

Python has a very nice httplib module as well as a url module which together will probably accomplish most of what you need (at least with regards to wget functionality).

Answer (score 0):

If you're used to dealing with cURL, consider [PycURL](http://pycurl.sourceforge.net/).